# Could not reach Cloud Firestore Backend when browser tab was inactive (AngularFire)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

In my Angular application, I have a home component that loads the content of a profile from Firestore via the provided URL (for example: mypage.com/username searches for a profile named "username"). Now I thought this was working fine but I noticed some very strange behaviour:

- loading a profile in an active tab (meaning the user is currently on this tab) always loads the profile
- opening the profile in a new, currently inactive tab (meaning the user has currently still opened a different tab) and letting the tab fully load also works
- opening the profile in a new tab and switching to it WHILE it's still loading produces the following error: **Could not reach Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds...**

In the last case Firestore throws an error and the query just returns an empty array. At this point I'd usually show a 404 message because I'd assume the profile couldn't be found (although it exists in this case). 
If this error occurs, the Firestore query still returns the result object when the tab goes active (user switches to this tab) but keep in mind that this happens AFTER it already threw an error and returned an empty array (and my actions (show 404) are based on the first result)

I am using @angular/fire 6.0.0 but this behaviour also exists with previous versions like 5.2.3.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

home.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
     let routeParam = param.get("id").toLowerCase()
     this.firebaseServcie.queryProfileByUniqueName(routeParam).subscribe(res => {
       if (res.length > 0) {
         //profile found ... some further actions
       }
       else {
         //profile not found ... usually show 404 message
       }
     });
   }
}
```

firebase.service.ts:

```
queryProfileByUniqueName(uniqueName: string): Observable<Profile[]> {
return this.firestore.collection<Profile>("profiles", ref => ref.where('uniqueName', '==', uniqueName))
  .valueChanges();
 }
```

---

I've made a workaround by iterating with `ngFor` over an Obervable array by using the `async` pipe. This kind of solves my issue but the error still get's thrown the way I described it above. I'd really like to find out if this is an issue from my side or from Firebase.

Comment: This isn't reproducible and has a lot of moving parts. A good amount of work could be done here to isolate the root cause and that would improve the chances of getting an answer. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This looks relevant: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/901

Comment: "(browser throttling the page when it's in a background tab)" - so this issue might be related to the browser? I would be surprised because I noticed this behaviour in Chrome as well as in Safari. 
I did not post a working example as creating a new Stackblitz with AngularFire imported, setting up a new Firebaseproject and connecting the two did not seem to be worth the effort for me if this was just a common problem with a design flaw on my side. Nevertheless I learned my lesson on how to ask questions around here if I want to get proper answers.

Comment: I'll post a working example here as soon as I have the time for it.

Answer (score 0):

> opening the profile in a new tab and switching to it WHILE it's still
>   loading produces the following error: Could not reach Firestore
>   backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds...

The reason for this is you have enabled persistence. Disable persistence and your error will be resolved.

With multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled in one tab at a time. Cloud Firestore's cache isn't automatically cleared between sessions.

This has been documented in Firebase docs

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence

Comment: Thanks for your answer but enabling persistence seems to be opt-in. I double checked everything but I did not import the AngularFirestoreModule with the `.enablePersistence(),` option.